# WCF Service connecting from AWS .Net Mock Lambda Test Tool in AWS Workspace but Failing when deployed to cloud or .net Core 6/.Net 4.8 Console App

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, wcf, aws-lambda

We have a Web Service which when run from our AWS Workspace is working fine and returning error as below when running it from our cloud.

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime,
> ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyRpc)
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(string, bool, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime, object[],
> object[], System.TimeSpan)
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MethodCall,
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime)
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(System.Reflection.MethodInfo,
> object[])
> generatedProxy_2.GetVersionContentsContext(OTDocumentMgmtService.GetVersionContentsContextRequest)

We have taken the same code and placed it in .Net 6 Console application as well as .net 4.8 Framework application which has resulted in the same exception. Below is the Service configuration in our reference.cs.

```
 System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
 result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
 result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
 result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
 result.AllowCookies = true;
 result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
 result.OpenTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);
 result.ReceiveTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);
 result.SendTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);
 result.MessageEncoding = System.ServiceModel.WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
 return result;
```

Comment: BasicHttpBinding.AllowCookies Property is only available in **.NET Framework versions 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0**. This could be the source of the problem. [BasicHttpBinding.AllowCookies Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.allowcookies?view=netframework-4.0)

Comment: Removed the key but still same and this is in the .net 6 application

Comment: What is your deployment environment? I wrote a simple service based on your config code that runs on Windows 10 Enterprise without problems.